# When to use arrays within JavaScript objects (or mix them)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Very often I see data structures like this:

```
var settings = {
    languages: [
        {
            language: 'English',
            translation: 'English',
            langCode: 'en',
            flagCode: 'us'
        },
        {
            ...
        }
    ]
};
```

Or this:

```
var settings = {
    languages: [
        {
            'en' : {
                language: 'English',
                translation: 'English',
                flagCode: 'us'
            }
        },
        {
            ...
        }
    ]
};
```

And this can go many levels deep (within an object there are often other arrays containing further objects)...

Adding arrays brings in another level of complexity when arrays have to be looped through to find a certain object, if we don't know its position in the array. But even if know its position it's still more complicated to use than using purely nested objects, where everything can easily be referred to, using dot notation. Like in this case:

```
var settings = {
    languages: {
        'en' : {
            language: 'English',
            translation: 'English',
            flagCode: 'us'
        },
        'de' : {
            ...
        }
    }
};
```

So when is it a good idea to use arrays within objects and when not?

Comment: arrays are well suited for looping through data, accessing data is not ONLY about using direct paths.
Arrays are also well suited for transformation, Javascript has many useful array manipulation methods (forEach, Some, Every, Splice, etc)
and when you DONT know about the data, arrays are very useful.

Comment: To add to Sebastien's points: arrays also preserve order, which is sometimes important (although seemingly not in the examples you posted).

Comment: The constructs you show are not very friendly in my opinions, `languages: ['en' : { },'de':{}]` or `languages: {'en' : { },'de':{}}` would be simpler to traverse

Comment: Good call about keeping ORDER, that's a VERY important differences.
@TedHopp

Comment: It's all about semantic structuring. If you hand an application such as linkedin, in the object representing a person where would you store the person's education (or experience)? Obviously in a property called education (... experience) of type array containing several other structured objects representing the educational items (... experience items). Which brings us back to Sebastien & Ted's comments -- the order of elements in our education array is relevant due to chronology.

Comment: Another good point is that ADDING objects to an array makes them that much more interesting in certain contexts. @MihaiStancu mention of Linkedin made me think of that.
Adding data to arrays is easy, its made to expand and shrink, whereas objects are sometimes "stiff"... or so to say.

Comment: Yes, using arrays for keeping the order totally makes sense.

Comment: @SebastienD. well i don't know about "stiff" when it comes to Dynamic languages which support any number of added properties on an object. If this were a question on any strong typed language with fixed-sized objects (C/C++/Java) I'd agree but in this case we can just as easily add items to an object as we would to an array.

Comment: People who downvote this question, please give a reason for doing so, so I can improve it. I'm sure that this is a question that many beginners face when meeting weird or seemingly illogical data structures. So instead of just pressing downvote, please take time and leave your reason for doing so.

Comment: @SebastienD. indeed there is a difference, while adding to an array, the code which uses the array will keep working out of the box. While adding to an object you'll have to either code for the new object-property or use the object as a simple hashmap (iterate over its properties) the way you would an array.

Comment: Didn't downvote myself, but my guess for the reason would be that the answer to "when to use an array in JavaScript" is "when you have a list of things".

Comment: @mplungjan this is what I thought..

Comment: @torazaburo, that's not that obvious.. you can nest a list of objects within another object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**My simple answer**

- Use objects (`{...}`) when you need a collection of `key:value` pairs
- Use arrays (`[...]`) when you need a collection of objects

**Other differences**

- arrays are ordered, objects are not
- arrays are automatically indexed with numbers, objects require you to specify an index
- arrays have a `.length` property, objects do not

Comment: ...well actualy, in JavaScript (as well as PHP) arrays and objects are implemented much the same way via an Ordered HashMap (or ordered Dictionary) meaning both arrays as well as objects are ordered if iterated upon with `for (a in b)`. Indeed if iterated upon with `for (var i=0; i<x.length; i++)` then you (not the language) would be retrieving items in a particular order.

Comment: @MihaiStancu there's no guaranteed order for your keys in an object. E.g., if you had an object `{a:1, b:2, c:3}`, when iterating through the the object's keys, there's no telling they'll come out as `a b c` or `b c a` or `c b a` etc

Comment: Indeed the order is not guaranteed by language specifications but as an implementation detail it is present. Also the clutter of inherited properties/methods is not very attractive when trying to access the properties you added to an object :-).

Comment: Objects have the length property too... they just count different stuff.

Comment: Thanks, this is a very good summary! Together with Sebastien D's comments it makes a good guide of when to use arrays within objects.

Comment: The only guarantee related to ordering of keys is that `Object.keys` will return the keys in the same order as `for (key in`.

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple reason behind doing this. One of them is,
When you need object in specific order array is helpful here. i.e. in your first example

```
var settings = {
    languages:
        {
            language: 'English',
            translation: 'English',
            langCode: 'en',
            flagCode: 'us'
        },
        {
            ...
        }
};
```

the inner object may shuffle it's position, when it's inside an array it will resides at it's index only.

Comment: This is not valid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

How would you like your data structure to hold a list of things if not an array?

Lets say you have an object that describes a `Person`, How would you hold the persons `Children`?

```
var kid1 = 
{
   FirstName: "Abc",
   LastName: "Def",
   Children: null
};

var kid2 = 
{
   FirstName: "Abc",
   LastName: "Def",
   Children: null
};

var dad = 
{
   FirstName: "Abc",
   LastName: "Def",
   Children: [kid1,kid2]
};

Children must be an array since a person can have more than one child.
```

Comment: Yes, this is a case where using arrays makes sense (tough it's a bit different than the example case).

Comment: It's not that different. A child is an object while Children is a collection of objects. Exactly like a languageDetails is an object while languages is a collection. Any other work around(e.g. holding an array as a key value object) will make the structure and you code more complicated and less readable.